# Making NSOpenGLViews fade in and out using NSViewAnimation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl

In the application I'm creating I wish to have certain `NSOpenGLViews` fade in and out of view when the user presses a button. Towards this end I've created a short test app using `NSViewAnimation`, attempting to fade out views over a duration of ten seconds. The code is closely based on that in [this post](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/AnimationGuide/Articles/ViewAnimations.html).

The code works perfectly for general objects inherited from `NSView`, for example an `NSBox` object, but when I attempt to use it with an `NSOpenGLView` object, the view does nothing for ten seconds and then suddenly disappears. Is there something extra I have to do to get `NSViewAnimation` to work with `NSOpenGLView`, or is `NSViewAnimation` not the right tool for the job in this case?

The relevant code:

```
// AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize theForeground;  // an instance of a the Foreground class - a subclass of NSOpenGLView
@synthesize theBox;
@synthesize theBackground;

//code omitted

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSViewAnimation *theAnim;
    NSMutableDictionary * theViewDict;

    theViewDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
    [theViewDict setObject: theForeground forKey:NSViewAnimationTargetKey];
    [theViewDict setObject:NSViewAnimationFadeOutEffect
                   forKey:NSViewAnimationEffectKey];

    theAnim = [[NSViewAnimation alloc] initWithViewAnimations:  [NSArrayarrayWithObject:theViewDict]];

    [theAnim setDuration:10.0];
    [theAnim setAnimationCurve:NSAnimationEaseInOut];

    [theAnim startAnimation];

    [theAnim release];
}
@end


// Foreground.m

#import "ForegroundView.h"

@implementation ForegroundView

// code omitted
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve the desired result by making a `CAOpenGLLayer` subclass to draw the OpenGL content. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CALayerEssentials/Listings/ExampleCAOpenGLLayer_h.html) for the Apple sample code. Fading in and out was then achieved by the following:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    static int isVisible = 1;
    [theGLView.layer setHidden: isVisible];
    isVisible = (isVisible + 1) % 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try assigning the NSOpenGLView as a subview of a container NSView whose alphaValue you set with the animator.

```
[[containerView animator] setAlphaValue: 0.0f];
```

It works well for me.

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but things are the same as with the original method. It works with `NSBox`, `NSButton` objects etc. but not with `NSOpenGLView` objects.